# I am finding monotone but it is saying bool object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

```
def ismonotone(a):
    n = len(a)
    for i in range(0, n-1) 
        if all(a[i] >= a[i+1] or a[i] <= a[i+1]):
            return True
        else:
            return False

A = [6, 5, 4, 2]
print(ismonotone(A))
```

Comment: The point of `all` is that it operates on a sequence and you don't have to write a `for` loop. You should review how to use it in simpler examples. Or alternatively, first write the same program without `all` and then see how to replace some parts of it with `all`.

Answer (score 1):

The result of comparison operator is either `True` or `False`. So inside your `all()` you have something like `True/False   or   True/False` which ends up to either `True` or `False`. That's why you get that error. `all()` accepts an iterable.

Also, for Monotonic you need to check *both* increasing and decreasing.

```py
def ismonotone(a):
    return (all(a[i] <= a[i + 1] for i in range(len(a) - 1)) or
            all(a[i] >= a[i + 1] for i in range(len(a) - 1)))

A = [6, 5, 4, 2]
print(ismonotone(A))  # True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if all(a[i]>=a[i+1]or a[i]<=a[i+1] ):
```

You're using `all()` incorrectly.  You're supposed to pass it a *sequence* of values, and it returns true if all of those values are true; otherwise it returns false.  You didn't pass a sequence of values.

But beyond that, it's not even clear what you wanted.  You're using `all()`, but then inside it you have an `or` condition.  So are you trying to check if BOTH of the conditions are true, or if EITHER is true?

In either case, a simple `and`/`or` expression is the right way to check.  So why are you using `all()` anyway?